# Do Jews interpret the destruction of the second temple as an act of judgment (as the destruction of the first temple was explained)?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

Do Jews interpret the destruction of the second temple as an act of judgment (as the destruction of the first temple was explained)?:

[What is the explanation for the destruction of the First Temple?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/what-is-the-explanation-for-the-destruction-of-the-first-temple)

Is the explanation likewise documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same piece of Talmud (Yoma 9b) quoted as the top-voted answer to the linked question regarding the first temple, records that the second temple was destroyed as a punishment for *sinat hinam* (gratuitous hatred between the Jews of the time).

Comment: Just wondering, are there any other opinions in the Talmud concerning why the Second Temple was destroyed? It seems the most "widespread" reason is for baseless hatred, but are there other reasons?

Comment: There is also the story of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza in Gittin 55b. It’s a little complicated to parse the precise message that the gemara is trying to teach with that story. Is it just an example of sinat hinam, or also a commentary on the rabbinic leadership of the time ? Or something else?

Comment: @ezra There are dozens of other options.

Comment: @DoubleAA You tell me there are dozens of other options, yet you bring none of them here. Care to cite a few?

Comment: @ezra see dupe (which I did bring here, just slightly higher on the page